# Correlation between two 3d arrays

Tags: r, correlation, computational-statistics

I know that a is related to b is related to c. I have data for two years: In 2018, d=10. In 2019, d=0. I would like to know the correlation between a, b and c, for both d=0 and d=10 in order to analyse the influence of d on the abc relationship.

I have generated one plot for d=0 and one for d=10, where x=a, y=b and fill=c, using geom_tile.

```
#r
mine.heatmap <- corr %>%
  filter(h>0 & h<10 & c>27) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b, fill = c)) +
  xlim(19,23) +
  ylim(25,50) +
  scale_fill_continuous(limits=c(-5, 15)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

The individual heatmaps for 2018 and 2019 gave me a good insight into the relationship between the three components. However, I am now looking to establish a correlation between the two heatmaps, so to speak. I was thinking of using corrgram() but I'm not sure whether I should be looking at six parameters; a_2018; a_2019; b_2018; b_2019; c_2018; c_2019, or if there's a method of drawing a simple correlation between Heatmap_2018 and Heatmap_2019.

This is an r issue as much as it is a question on statistics, both of which are new to me. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you after a canonical correlation? https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/canonical-correlation-analysis/ Or have I misread your question?

Comment: @PaulHewson That's the thing; I'm not sure.  In the example you've provided, psych and acad consist of different categorical variables, whereas I have two dfs which consist of identical variables a,b, c, with the only difference being that for df1, d=10 and for df2, d=0.  I'm not sure if a correlation between a1, a2, b1, b2, c1 and c2 will help identify the influence of d on the data. In other words, I'm not sure if I should be looking at canonical correlation.

Comment: Hi Eugene. OK, how does mediation analysis sound? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf